# Correct KO binding to access objects within an array?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel, single-page-application, durandal

I've got the following code and I believe the ViewModel is structured correctly (I could be wrong) but I can't seem to access the values properly.

### The JavaScript Pieces

NOTE: I'm using the Hot Towel SPA template with DurandalJS and `<!-- ko compose -->` style binding but I'm not showing that here to keep it simple.

```
var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    title: 'People',
    people: [
        new PersonItem('TestFirst', 'TestLast', 'first@last.com', '111.111.1111', 'bio here'),
        new PersonItem('TestFirst2', 'TestLast2', 'first2@last2.com', '222.222.2222', 'bio here')

    ],
    mytext: 'Oh Hey There'
};

return vm;

function PersonItem(firstname, lastname, email, phone, shortbio) {
    var firstName = firstname;
    var lastName = lastname;
    var emailAddress = email;
    var phoneNumber = phone;
    var shortBio = shortbio;

    var fullName = function () {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    };

    var imagePath = function() {
        return "/Content/images/Bio_" + firstName + "_" + lastName + ".jpg";
    };

    var resumePath = function () {
        return "/Content/Resumes/resume_" + firstName + "_" + lastName + ".pdf";
    };
```

### The Binding I'm Trying

```
<div data-bind="text: mytext"></div>

<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li data-bind="text: firstName"></li>
</ul>
```

### The Problem

I see a bullet is created, which seems to indicate the collection is being found, but the way I'm trying to access "firstName" doesn't seem to be working correctly.

I see the following (note that the text string is binding so I know knockout is doing its thing):

[image]

I know this is likely a simple oversight on my part but I just can't seem to see it and Google has me coming up empty (likely because I'm not sure exactly what to search for).

Comment: mind making a jsfiddle? i'm on my iphone and can't right now thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your PersonItem you defined firstName as a private property as of the variable declaration.
This indicates that it is only visible inside the Class itself.

Try changing it to

```
this.firstName = firstname;
```

also you may wan't to think about using observables, if the values are going to change that would yield.

```
this.firstName = ko.observable(firstname);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Knew it was a simple oversight. Thank you!

Comment: I would also change your functions inside to computeds so that if the observables change the view is automatically updated

Answer (score 0):

It's because your firstName is declared as var so it's private variable inside function, and not property of object returned by constructor. Use `this.firstName` instead `var firstName`.

Your code working in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hC5Hf/

There was missing closing bracket of your function and activate is commented out in vm since it don't exist in your example.